# apscheduler interval task is not running on aws

Tags: python, python-3.x, amazon-web-services, amazon-elastic-beanstalk, apscheduler

I would like to fire my job every few minutes. It is working on my local machine. However, on AWS Elastic Beanstalk the job never fires. I use python 3.4, apscheduler 3.1.0 and Flask 0.10.1.

For instance:

```
from apscheduler.schedulers.background import BackgroundScheduler

def my_job()
    print('Hello')


scheduler = BackgroundScheduler()
scheduler.add_job(my_job, 'interval', seconds=120, id='my_job')
scheduler.start()
```

Any ideas why it doesn't work on AWS?

Comment: How do you know it's not working? Does `print` output to one of Beanstalk's logs or would `logging` be better?

Comment: There is nothing in the logs, also it is just an example. I have few tasks and all of them should insert status to a database. The problem was with uWSGI (I still surprise why it doesn't mentioned on the apscheduler web page) that doesn't support threads by default. Could find a way to turn them on on AWS, so I just did it using cron.

Comment: you need not enable-threads

Answer (score 0):

you can use like this.

```
@application.before_first_request
def initialize():
    scheduler = BackgroundScheduler()
    scheduler.add_job(my_job, 'interval', seconds=120, id='my_job')
    scheduler.start()
```